# Print recurring lines of output to a text file

Tags: windows, batch, automation, cmd.exe

I want to write the following to a text file:

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
```

and so on until reaching a certain number of lines output.

I have to type around 3500 similar lines. How do I automate this? I am working on Windows so a batch file would be appropriate. Can a `FOR LOOP` with `ECHO` be used from the command line to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
powershell 0..3500^|%{'a{0:0####}:' -f $_}>number.txt
```

Result, number.txt:

```
a00000:
a00001:
a00002:
```

...

```
a03500:
```

If need your line -

```
powershell 1..3500^|%{'a{0:}'-f $_}>number2.txt
```

Result, number2.txt:

```
a1
a2
a3
```

...

```
a3500
```

Answer (score 1):

From command line:

```
(for /L %G in (1,1,3500) do @echo a%G)>anumbers.txt
```

From batch:

```
(for /L %%G in (1,1,3500) do @echo a%%G)>anumbers.txt
```

Surround path to output file with double quotes if contain spaces as follows:

```
(for /L %%G in (1,1,3500) do @echo a%%G)>"my files\a numbers.txt"
```

---

Note `()` parentheses and `>` redirector. Better (more effective) than `>>` redirector without parentheses, which will open and close the resulting file 3500 times:

```
for /L %%G in (1,1,3500) do @echo a%%G>>anumbers.txt
```

Resources:

- [`FOR /L` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) (Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers)
- [`>` redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)